# Markdown to pdf: page marking

Tags: pdf-generation, markdown

I want to make pdf from markdown: write markdown and convert it into pdf.
Can I do page marking by means of a markdown?

I understand as "a page marking" transition to new page, location of a line to page center across, text location in page center, etc.

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the best way to get about doing this is to do a Markdown-HTML-PDF convertion. Your markdown implementation should be able to generate HTML and then use something like [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) (ruby) or the underlying [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to go from HTML to PDF. The wicked_pdf documentation outlines how to do page numbering with the help of some javascript. For page breaking you should be able to use CSS to keep things together and force page breaks. Check out page-break-inside and page-break-after for this. There is a discussion about it in the [wkhtmltopdf manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html).